# Замена HDD RAID 1 на более ёмкий HDD [ubuntu]

Tags: ubuntu, hdd, raid

Есть система Ubuntu 16.04 которая стоит на Software Raid 1. Какими способами можно заменить все HDD в RAID 1 на более ёмкие? Короче говоря, нужно перенести систему с Software RAID 1 160G на Software RAID 1 500G.

Comment: а просто последовательно заменить не получается?

Comment: У меня было проще. Система - на отдельном HDD без RAID. А хардовый RAID только для данных. Переехал со 160 Гб на 1 Тб простым копированием.

Comment: А Software RAID он с помощью какого Software, того что в linux, т.е. mdadm или что то другое

Comment: @Mike с помощью mdadm собран.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Рейд вероятно собран через `linux raid`, более известный как `mdadm`.

Если есть возможность все 4 диска сразу подключить, то подключаете все диски, размечаете как необходимо. Затем расширяете массив на все 4 диска, raid1 можно без проблем менять число дисков в массиве.

```
mdadm /dev/mdX -a /dev/sdcX
mdadm /dev/mdX -a /dev/sddX
mdadm --grow /dev/mdX -n 4
```

Ждёте окончание синхронизации. После этого убираете старые диски и сужаете массив обратно до 2 дисков.

```
mdadm /dev/mdX -f /dev/sdaX
mdadm /dev/mdX -r /dev/sdaX
mdadm /dev/mdX -f /dev/sdbX
mdadm /dev/mdX -r /dev/sdbX
mdadm --grow /dev/mdX -n 2
```

Всё, массив теперь живёт на новых дисках, стрые диски можно физически отключать. Теперь можно сказать mdadm, что надо увеличить размер массива командой

```
mdadm --grow /dev/mdX --size=max
```

Дальнейшие действия в зависимости от того, что на массиве расположено. Если файловая система - то смотря какая файловая система: `xfs_growfs`, `resize2fs` или что-то другое. Если LVM - то командой `pvresize` можно сказать, что размер устройства изменился.

Если есть возможности подключить только два диска - то поочерёдно отключаете один старый, добавляете один новый, ждёте синхронизацию массива, отключаете второй старый диск, ставите второй новый. Затем продолжаете с `--grow --size=max`. Расширить массив на новые диски и только после синхронизации вынимать старые немного надёжнее для пограничного случая, когда вынули 1 диск, а при синхронизации с новым оставшийся старый диск неожиданно помер.

Comment: Большое спасибо. То что нужно.

Comment: Дабы не плодить отдельную тему (или нужно?), а как заменить RAID 1 HDD на более ёмкие но уже в windows 10 (также сделан программный RAID встроенными средствами Windows)?

Comment: Лучше плодите тему. Не имею ни малейшего представления, не работаю с виндами.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.