# Как безопасно заменить работающий диск в linux raid?

Tags: linux, hdd, raid

Есть программный RAID5 собранный через `mdadm` (`linux raid`). И есть необходимость заменить один из пока ещё исправных томов массива на новый диск. Обычно это делается через отметку старого диска как неисправного и добавление нового диска с восстановлением массива:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 -f /dev/sdd1
mdadm /dev/md0 -r /dev/sdd1
mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdc1
```

Но перестраивается массив довольно долго и подвержен риску потерять весь массив при ошибке какого-то ещё диска. Возможно ли как-то использовать исправный старый том во время добавления нового и так минимизировать риск для массива?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[По мотивам ответа](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74924/how-to-safely-replace-a-not-yet-failed-disk-in-a-linux-raid5-array) на `unix.SO`, такая возможность была добавлена [в ядро linux](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=2d78f8c451785f030ac1676a18691896b59c69d8) в версии 3.2 (релиз начала 2012 года) и сопутствующие опции появились в [mdadm версии 3.3](https://github.com/neilbrown/mdadm/commit/70c55e36b73827579fcb2dadbb6359ef605191ff) (релиз в 2013 год был). Поэтому если у вас достаточно свежее ПО, то необходимо добавить новый диск в массив (добавится как `spare`):

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdc1
```

И запросить выполнить замену диска командой:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --replace /dev/sdd1 --with /dev/sdc1
```

Эта команда запросит замену диска sdd на sdc. Параметр `with` необязателен, если его не указать - то будет использован любой `spare` диск.

После этой команды начнётся долгий процесс записи данных на новый диск, после того как новый том будет синхронизирован - он автоматически заменит собой старый. Старый диск sdd при этом будет отмечен как failed и его необходимо будет удалить из массива как обычно:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 -r /dev/sdd1
```

---

Если у вас есть только подходящее ядро 3.2+, но старая версия `mdadm` - то вы можете выполнить такие же операции напрямую через `sysfs` псевдосистему, сначала добавив новый `spare` диск

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdc1
```

Затем запросить замену:

```
echo want_replacement > /sys/block/md0/md/dev-sdd1/state
```

В общем-то именно это и делает `mdadm`, потому итог будет таким же: старый диск во время синхронизации нового диска будет работать как обычно, затем станет `failed`.

---

А вот если ядро более старое - то тогда печально и что-то однозначно удачное предложить сложно.

---

Указанный способ поддерживается для RAID4/5/6 и RAID10. Поддержки RAID1 нет по той простой причине, что в RAID1 уже существенно более давно можно свободно налету менять число дисков в массиве. То есть вместо операции замены одного диска [можно расширить массив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637836/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-hdd-raid-1-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%91%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-hdd-ubuntu/637847#637847) с двух дисков до трёх, дождаться штатного перестроения, удалить старый диск и сменить число дисков в массиве обратно до 2. Так всё время сохраняются минимум 2 копии данных.

Answer (score 1):

Если например у вашего raid5 три диска попробуйте добавить четвёртый, одновременно реорганизовать в raid6. Так как у raid6 безопасность предоставляет два сбойных диска можете спокойно пить кофе. Добавляем в raid5 запасной диск:

```
> mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdc
```

Реорганизуемся в raid6:

```
>mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --level=6 --raid-devices=4 --backup-file=/root/raid5backup
```

Далее удаляем один подозрительный диск:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 -f /dev/sdd1
mdadm /dev/md0 -r /dev/sdd1
```

И возвращаемся назад в raid5 :

```
>mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 --backup-file=/root/raid5backup
```

*Файл для безопасного копирования `/root/raid5backup` небольшого размера должен находится физически НЕ в данном массиве.*

Comment: Имеет смысл добавить явное указание, что backup-file должен быть не на этом же самом массиве.